# CREATE TABLE...LIKE not preserving primary keys in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I'm creating a copy of a table using the CREATE TABLE... LIKE statement in Redshift, and the copy is working, but primary key is not being preserved.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE orig_table);
```

Am I missing a parameter that should be specified to ensure this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html#r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW-parameters)

> **Tables created with the LIKE option don't inherit primary and foreign key constraints.** Distribution style, sort keys, BACKUP, and NULL properties are inherited by LIKE tables, but you can't explicitly set them in the CREATE TABLE ... LIKE statement.